# k-closest point to a specific target

Tags: python

I try to find a k closest points to a target. For example, I have this set of point:

```
points = [(0,0), (19, 8), (23, 11), (25, 22), (30, 26), (23, 20), (30,0)]
```

And I want to find the k-closest point for each element of the list. I have tried this code:

```
def kClosest(target, points,k):
    return sorted(points, key=lambda x:(target[0]-x[0])**2+(target[1]-x[1])**2)[:k]

for i in points:
    points_copy = points.copy()
    points_copy.remove(i)
    print(i, ": ", kClosest(i,points_copy,3))
```

The output will be like this (which I expect):

```
(0, 0) :  [(19, 8), (23, 11), (30, 0)]
(19, 8) :  [(23, 11), (23, 20), (30, 0)]
(23, 11) :  [(19, 8), (23, 20), (25, 22)]
(25, 22) :  [(23, 20), (30, 26), (23, 11)]
(30, 26) :  [(25, 22), (23, 20), (23, 11)]
(23, 20) :  [(25, 22), (23, 11), (30, 26)]
(30, 0) :  [(23, 11), (19, 8), (23, 20)]
```

Now I want to modify the output to result in **the index** of the points. So, I hope the output for point `(0,0)` is `[1, 2, 6]`. How can we modify the code to produce the expected output?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Neighbors module from sklearn:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/classes.html#module-sklearn.neighbors

This will provide you optimized methods to do this.

Answer (score 0):

I also think that you should use some optimized module like the one from Sklearn as stated in @aurelien_morel answer.
In any case a very simple solution for what you are asking is to work with indexes of the list `points` and use them to get and order by the values and return them.

```
points = [(0,0), (19, 8), (23, 11), (25, 22), (30, 26), (23, 20), (30,0)]
def kClosest(target, points,k):
    return sorted(range(len(points)), key=lambda idx:(target[0]-points[idx][0])**2+(target[1]-points[idx][1])**2)[:k]

for i in points:
    points_copy = points.copy()
    points_copy.remove(i)
    print(i, ": ", kClosest(i,points_copy,3))
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a rather primitive method of getting what you need, but doesn’t involve using sklearn: before calling `kClosest()` add the index of the point to its value, like this:

```
points_with_index = [l+[i] for i,l in enumerate(points)]
```

Use `points_with_index` in your call to `kClosest()` instead of `points`. Now when you print value from points_with_index use value[2] to show just the original index.